# Why is there an asymmetry in QM?

Tags: philosophy-of-physics

In discussions of quantum mechanics (QM), a classical system observes a quantum system. There is an asymmetry that observation occurs in only one direction, this is at very different from Newtonian Mechanics when a force applied from A to B implies another force from B to A.

Can one discuss in QM, a system A that is observing B but which at the same time B is observing A?

Comment: Are you asking about observers, or about decoherence? Thermodynamics is your answer either way

Comment: @CraiglCragl: Decoherence is one explanation of the collapse postulate. However I'm asking about classical QM, if classical is the right word to use here.

Comment: The observation is reciprocal, but larger systems are more statistically stable.  The reciprocity is one explanation (Bohm's ?) of the cause of necessary uncertainty.  I as a macroscopic organism can see myself as *the* observer because the intensive coordination between my parts makes the effects upon me and the particle I am observing highly disproportionate.  But really, there is not a distinction.

Comment: "Observing" is an example of interaction, in both CM and QM interaction always goes both ways. The difference is that in CM one can always reduce the backreaction of the observed to arbitrarily small amount, and in QM due to the uncertainty principle one can not. The reason we have to use classical systems to do the observing has more to do with our macroscopic nature than with QM itself.

Comment: @conifold: The point I'm making is we always in Classical Mechanics look at reciprocal actions this isn't the case the standard examples of the QM. There may be have been people who have studied this though, I'm just not aware of it.

Comment: I am not sure I follow. When we observe planets through a telescope we hardly care about the effect this would have on the planets. The same with measuring temperature or pressure, technically one can not do that without affecting what is measured, but with little care this can almost always be neglected. Bohr's early interpretation of QM ascribed quantum uncertainty to unavoidable observer interference absent in CM, so if anything the asymmetry would go the other way (but this interpretation is now known to be non-viable).

Comment: @conifold: Sure, there the asymmetry is so large that we can neglect the back-reaction this has. Nevertheless Newtonian mechanics is symmetric in the way it talks about force. If we talk about one atom observing another it seems unsuprising we can ask the question does the latter observe the former. Of course QM doesn't talk about such small systems as observers per se, but here I'm taking my cue from relational QM where any system can be considered as an observer.

Comment: Decoherence is not only an explanation of wavefunction collapse, decoherence is an observed property of quantum mechanical systems. Specifically, it's the property of those systems to decohere to their environment, losing information if you view it from an information theoretic standpoint. Objects that are small enough to have their QM properties noticeable exhibit decoherence, that aspect of it has nothing to do with which interpretation of QM you want to believe in. Even if you believe 'classical' (orthodox?) QM, particles still decohere into their environment through ambient interactions.

Comment: If decoherence was only applicable to it's own philosophy of QM, why would quantum computer scientists be so worried about their ability to build large scale quantum computers, error correcting algorithms and hardware, etc? That's the kind of decoherence that is relevant to this question. And to the larger point, Conifold is correct that the reason it's always presented as a classical system looking at a QM system is because we are classical systems and the instruments we use are classical because we're macroscopic, not because QM particles can't measure other QM particles. That's decoherence.

Comment: @not_here: Nevertheless some people argue that the collapse postulate isn't basic and is a result of decoherence. That is what I was talking about. It seems fairly obvious to me that something like decoherence would be true for large systems interacting with small quantum systems. However what I was asking has nothing to do with this. Do I need to mention all this merely to ask a question?

Comment: The [many-worlds interpretation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Many-worlds_interpretation) solves the asymmetry in your example.

> Many-worlds implies that all possible alternate histories and futures are real, each representing an actual "world" (or "universe").

Symmetry is established since "A observes B" has a symmetric partner world where "B observes A"

Comment: @draks: interesting idea.

Comment: @draks: by the way I'm glad some-one got the idea behind the question!

Comment: @MoziburUllah Decoherence *does* play a role in what you're talking about. You said "Decoherence is one explanation of the collapse postulate. However I'm asking about classical QM" which seems to very implicitly state that you don't believe decoherence has anything to do with the Copenhagen orthodox interpretation of QM, which I was explaining is an incorrect belief. You asked "can a system A that is observing B but which at the same time B is observing A?" and the answer is yes, that's what happens when, for example, qubits decohere into their environment, even if you assume Copenhagen QM.

Comment: I'm joining to vote to close because this question seems to be about a misunderstanding of how QM works, from a mathematical or physical standpoint, and not a question about the philosophical interpretation of QM or anything else relating to philosophy. Systems can measure each other, it happens all the time, that isn't a philosophical question.

Comment: @Not_here: Vote how you like. You're obviously want to believe that I know nothing about QM and would rather jump to conclusions. This question has nothing to do about decoherence which is why I'm dismissive about it. It has nothing to do about my attitude towards it. I'm dismissive towards it, in part, because it's a derived phenomena; and when I said that it 'explains the collapse postulate', then in that sense it's a fundamental process.

Comment: @not_here: if you feel that decoherence plays a part in answering my question. Fine, put it an answer.  At least Draks understood the question without quibbling over my understanding of QM ... which to my mind shows that I'm not being totally perverse in the way I phrased the question.

Answer (score 1):

The [many-worlds interpretation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Many-worlds_interpretation) (MWI) solves the asymmetry in your example.

> Many-worlds implies that all possible alternate histories and futures are real, each representing an actual "world" (or "universe").

Symmetry is established since "A observes B" has a symmetric partner world where "B observes A"

I admit I favor the "collapse of the wave function" interpretation, but please feel free to pick your own favorite interpretation [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interpretations_of_quantum_mechanics).

---

Back to the question in the title "Why is there an asymmetry in QM?", I'd like to add the following:

Observing a quantum system (made up of a superposition of eigenstates), collapses the wave function to a single eigenstate of your observation operator and by that destroys superposition. More important: the observer A gathers information about the system B*. The (asymmetric) information flow from B to A drives change in the world...

*: This can be shown, because the information can be erased (by so called quantum erasers) while traveling to the observer A. By that, the superposition state is not affected.

Comment: I'm not a big fan of the many-worlds interpretation but as I've already mentioned I like this answer! It might make me think again about many-worlds...

Answer (score 0):

Especially during the initial formation and development of QM, as far as what physicists write down in their notebooks as “measurements”, they are all classical outcomes.  So having a theory that allows one to predict classical observations make sense.  Several of the developers of the theory were in the thrall of logical positivism, and thus they were only concerned with constructing a theory that was empirically adequate for computing the results of the kinds of experiments that they could conceive of.

More recently study of quantum decoherence and related phenomena are providing a more complete QM description of the types of interactions that yield essentially classical results.  My impression is that from some people in that field you hear the problem as being more of "how does one get an effective classical theory given that the 'real world' is quantum mechanical"?

Answer (score -1):

You seem to have got off on the wrong foot, by comparing observing, to force. For an example of a classical account of the effects of observation, look at https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maxwell%27s_demon The key is accounting for information transfer and persistence, not force.

The next problem, is the nature of the superposition of states. An observer, by definition, collapses such a superposition into a definite state by taking an observation. That doesn't neccessarily stop the 'observer' being subatomic, or quantum mechanical, just not in a superposition. Quantum superpositions can interact with each other, making a combined superposition. Observation always means collapse of the wave function and information out into the wider world about it's state.

Also, you are using the word symmetry in a suspect way. You can say Newton's third law states a symmetrical reaction. But symmetry in general related to forces, is likely to be taken as gauge symmetry.

Comment: I actually think 'observation' is closer to the notion of force than of observation; but here I'm not thinking of Newtonian force but abstract Aristotelian notion of force which is merely that which causes change. I don't see why the observering system can't be in a super-position with respect to the observed system, though admittedly that isn't a situation that is usually discussed in textbooks.

Comment: Yes you have made that clear. But your unconventional use of these words has mainly  led to lots of confused questions. The nature of quantum mechanics is linked to what the small possible probe is, the information carrier that can interfere least while gathering information. A system, a superposition, must be small enough that no information carriers enter or exit, so that it acts like a black box, the state invisible until a probe acts on it, opening the box. The scale of coherence is limited by how large a system can be isolated from all probes.

Comment: @craiglcragl: Which unconventional use?

Comment: Force, observation, symmetry.

Comment: the uses I put those concepts to in the question are conventional: 'a *force* is applied from A to B', 'a classical system *observes* a quantum system', that Newtons third law is symmetric is standard. So I'm not sure why you think I'm using these words 'unconventionally'. Sure, I used them unconventionally in the comment above, but I indicated this.